# Const array pointer to const values

Tags: c++, arrays, constants, const-correctness

If I create a global array of const values, e.g.

```
const int SOME_LIST[SOME_LIST_SIZE] = {2, 3, 5, 7, 11};
```

is it possible for SOME_LIST to be modified in any way?

How can I write this such that SOME_LIST points to a const memory location, and is a const pointer itself (i.e. cannot be pointed somewhere else)?

Comment: `SOME_LIST` can't be modified in anyway

Comment: `SOME_LIST` is [an array, not a pointer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4810664/), so there is only one level of constness to worry about.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The way you have it is correct.

Also, you don't need to provide `SOME_LIST_SIZE`; C++ will figure that out automatically from the initializer.

Comment: Just to confirm, if I tried to point it somewhere else or memset it, a compiler error would be thrown?

Comment: @Darthfett: Yes, it would. Someone particularly malicious might be able use `const_cast` on it, but as a not-pointer, I'm fairly certain that's treading into undefined behavior territory.

Comment: Of course: an array cannot be relocated, and `memset` would complain that you are giving to it a `const` pointer. Obviously you could bypass this last protection with a `const_cast`, but then you go into UB-land (it may result in a crash at runtime).

Comment: `const int SOME_LIST[]` decays to `const int *` when passed to a function.  Isn't the OP asking for a way to define `SOME_LIST[]` such that it will decay to `const int * const`?

Answer (score 20):

There are 3 main examples of pointers which involve the "const" keyword. (See this [link](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/const_correctness.html))

Firstly: Declaring a pointer to a constant variable. The pointer can move, and change what is it pointing to, but the variable cannot be modified.

```
const int* p_int;
```

Secondly: Declaring an "unmovable" pointer to a variable. The pointer is 'fixed' but the data can be modified. This pointer must be declared and assigned, else it may point to NULL, and get fixed there.

```
int my_int = 100;
int* const constant_p_int = &my_int;
```

Thirdly: Declaring an immovable pointer to constant data.

```
const int my_constant_int = 100; (OR "int const my_constant_int = 100;")
const int* const constant_p_int = &my_constant_int;
```

You could also use this.

```
int const * const constant_p_int = &my_constant_int;
```

Another good reference see [here](http://duramecho.com/ComputerInformation/WhyHowCppConst.html). I hope this will help, although while writing this I realize your question has already been answered...

Comment: I was familiar with the use of const on pointers, it was simply arrays that I was unsure of.  Still very good things to know. :)

Comment: Yes I was only recently getting my head around it, so thought I might share (: